# SSRS Print Counter

Tags: report, reporting-services

I'm quite new to SSRS and I've almost completed the report I was asked to do, everything is working as intended but my client just asked me to indicated how much time the report has been printed in it current form, in the header of the said report.

So my report has 2 parameters: the beginning date and the ending date.

Let's say my client brings up a report for the 05-05-2005 to 06-06-2006 period and prints it would indicate "REPORT NAME (Print #1)" in the header/title. And then if he decides to come back a week later and print the same exact report it would indicate "REPORT NAME (Print #2)".

Is there anyways to do this? So far my researches leads me to believe it's not possible.

Thanks in advance for any leads/solutions !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to write a [custom Print delivery extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154050.aspx) to record the "print" in a database somewhere. So practically, no, in "pure" SSRS

Ideas:

- An approximation of this would be to log the query to the database, when the report is rendered. You don't know if the report is acxtually printed though
- Use a ReportViewer control or some other programmatic method to launch and print in one go: so a database query *is* a print. And log it, as above.

Comment: Thanks, creating a log in my database was my next step :D

Answer (score 3):

For future readers: There is no need to create your own query logging.

You can query the ReportServer.dbo.ExcecutionLog table. It contains a lot of information about report requests including the parameters in XML format. You can do a group/count on that to determine the number of previous executions of a specific report.

more info on extracting info from the Execution Log here:
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155836(v=sql.90).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155836%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Only problem is still determining if the user printed the report. You may also be able to derive this from ExecutionLog:

- the Format column - this should be "Image (emf)" or something like that for printouts.
- Also, a print action most likely happens just after a HTML render action, with the same ExecutionID and / or Source = "Session"

See for yourself what logs a Printout generate: query Executionlog sorted by executionstart, display a report, requery, print, requery etc.